# How do I safely deprecate fields in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on an API that involves creating datastore entities and reading them back after some time from an asynchronous callback. I am trying to remove fields safely and more easily rollback, by updating the struct passed to the golang datastore library, but am facing errors when removing fields because the new code cannot handle the entity structure created by the old code.

old code:

```
type Entity struct {
  ActiveField string
  UnusedField string // TODO: deprecate
}

value := Entity{ActiveField: "my-value"}

client.Put(ctx, key47, value)
```

new code:

```
type Entity struct {
  ActiveField string
}
value := Entity{}
err := client.Get(ctx, key47, value) // --> error
```

When I remove a field from the struct used for getting and putting entities, I get the following error:

```
datastore: cannot load field "UnusedField" into a "service.Entity": no such struct field
```

The only workaround that I have found was in this [github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/913#issuecomment-817461420):

```
err := datastore.get()
if err != nil && !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "no such struct field") {
  return err
}
```

I'm wondering (A) if this is correct, would still get all the other fields, and (B) what are the best practices around backward compatibility using datastore.

Comment: you can still keep your old struct and get database entity into it. then create another struct that has unnecessary fields removed. then marshal | unmarshal old struct to new struct

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV thanks! the trick is that I can't load the datastore entity into the new struct because of the error. retrieval happens at a different time, maybe weeks later, in a different runtime and maybe version. let me know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs at https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#section-readme

> Fields may have a `datastore:"name,options"` tag. The tag name is the property name, which must be one or more valid Go identifiers joined by ".", but may start with a lower case letter. An empty tag name means to just use  the field name. A "-" tag name means that the datastore will ignore that field.
>
> The only valid options are "omitempty", "noindex" and "flatten".

I expect you want to go from

```
type Entity struct {
   ActiveField string
   UnusedField string // TODO: deprecate
 }
```

to

```
type Entity struct {
   ActiveField string
   FormerlyUsedForBlah string `datastore:"FormerName,omitempty,noindex"`
 }
```

OR

```
type Entity struct {
   ActiveField string
   UnusedField string `datastore:"-"`
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @JimMorrison! I didn't know that datastore supported tags. Those options would work, but the goal is to remove those fields altogether, not keep them with tags. Wait, oooh-- are you saying that by using `datastore:"-"` at insertion time, the entities which are PUT in datastore will not have those fields, so when a new version of the code GETs them, it will not error if the new struct doesn't have UnusedField? (If that makes sense)